# Setting Expiration Time on data stored using Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, cookies, isolatedstorage

Is it possible to set an expiration time on the data stored in Isolated Storage like we can do for cookies? Can we have something similar to Session cookie in Isolated Storage?

Answer (score 1):

No... isolated storage is for permanent storage so it doesn't make sense to delete automatically (since cookies are temporary files)..
The work around may be :
Store another parameter in isolatedstorage specifying time when to expire..
so when the app opens just check for this date and delete the files as per your need.. :)